# How to install NetBeans C/C++ compiler?

Tags: netbeans

What tools do I need instaled in NetBeans to build C++ programs? I don't have anything in "Tool Collections" in Options>C/C++. How can I add this tools in the most simple way?
What is the standard tools for C++ programm execution, debug, syntaxis

Answer (score 6):

In Linux you have to install `gcc` and `g++`. In windows you can use [`cygwin`](http://cygwin.com/setup.exe). Download and install by choosing appropriate options.

[image]

In the search box search for `gcc`, `gdb` and `make`. Mark `Install` for all three in the "Devel" development tools category.

Then, go to netbeans, Tools -> Options -> C/C++

Click Restore defaults.

Comment: *“In the search box search for "gcc" "gdb" "make" and mark "install" for all three.”* Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: This is the search box for Cygwin packages. It generally pops up during Cygwin install (which is probably why Andrey assumed you noticed it) or it's accessible through cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

[Installing and Configuring C/C++ Support](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/60/cpp-setup-instructions.html)